# How do I make Xunit test class and use constructor parameters like TestFixture with parameters in Nunit?

Tags: c#, xunit

In Nunit I can do something like this:

```
[TestFixture("param1")]
[TestFixture("param2")]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    public MyTestFixture(string param) { /* more code */ }
    /* more code */
}
```

After that all the tests and test cases inside class `MyTestFixture` will run twice, using parameters from `TestFixture` attributes one by one. Xunit doesn't use attribute `TestFixture`, so how can I do similar thing without specifying those two parameters in each test inside `InlineData`? If I do, it doubles the amount of attributes in my test code. I can write constructor with parameters, but I didn't find the way to pass data there. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the XUnit developers closed this issue and mentioned that they will not be adding in support for this back in 2015:

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/352

A few users within the GitHub thread have posted their alternate solutions for working around the lack of support for parameterized TestFixtures, which may help resolve your issue.